# Add item in ObservableCollection Ordered - C# UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app, observablecollection

I have one issue, this is very boring and I spend many time to do resolve my problem with the best way.

Problem: I Have two ObservableCollections. (OCAux - Auxiliar OC, OCMain - Main OC Binded UI)

I have request http, 5 requests. for each response to the request is added to items OCAux, and are then ordered the items. After this is added to each item ordered to my OCMain and this automatically notifies the UI (is binding). The problem is that when adding a new item, this is not ordered because I'm order is the result of OCAux, ie only orders request on request. If you order the item after you add them to OCMain it does flashes.
I could order the OCMain for every time that added items, but causes the UI flashes while adding the items.

This was circumvented as follows, but there remains these "flashes" in the UI:

```
                    foreach (var item in OCMain)
                    {
                        OCAux.Add(item);
                    }

                    ObservableCollection<Movies> moviesSortedByDatetime= new ObservableCollection<Movies>
                    (OCAux.OrderByDescending(item=> item.DateTime));

                    OCMain.Clear();

                    foreach (var item in moviesSortedByDatetime)
                    {
                        if (!OCMain.Contains(item))
                        { 
                          OCMain.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
```

Anyone know how to hold insert an item in the correct position of a ObservableCollection?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add it to OCAux. Then order it. Get the index of added item using OCAux.indexOf(item). Then insert it to OCMain. OCMain.Insert(index,item); Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I do the sort in the CollectionViewSource but I only know WPF.  And another trick is to return an IEnumerable you sort and call NotifyProperty change on the enumeralble but that does not work in all situations.  Pretty sure and ObservableCollection does not have an InsertAt.

Answer (score 0):

For batch inserts to constantly update UI for each change may be (unless you need *real-time* updates). Unless you have a good reason to keep `OCAux` then I'd make `OCMain` an ordered collection with custom `IObservableCollection` implementation to postpone notifications after a batch has been completed. It can be done in two ways:

1) Simplest one is to add a `BeginUpdate()` method where you disable notifications. When you finished your job with the collection then you re-enable notifications with `EndUpdate()`. Proof of concept for a class inherited from `ObservableCollection<T>`:

```
public void BeginUpdate() {
    _disableNotifications = true;
}

public void EndUpdate() {
    _disableNotifications = false;

    if (_changed) {
        OnCollectionChanged(
            new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));

        _changed = false;
    }
}

protected override OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (_disableNotifications)
        _changed = true;
    else
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
}
```

Just apply same logic also for `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface raising event `PropertyChanged` for `Count` and `Items` properties.

2) Second option is little bit more complicate but it works even if you don't know when batch operation starts and ends. First of all let's make an assumption: users won't notice if updates are delayed by 100 ms. In this case what we can do is to *ignore* changes and send just one `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` after `NotificationDelay` milliseconds. It doesn't matter how many updates you have, just one will be sent after `NotificationDelay` milliseconds from first one. Proof of concept:

```
protected override OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    // Another event already queued a delayed notification
    if (_isTimerRunning)
        return;

    // Assuming _timer is a System.Timers.Timer object already configured
    // and OnTimerElapsed method attached to its Elapsed event. Note that
    // you may also use System.Threading.Timer, pick the proper one
    // according to MSDN and your requirements
    _isTimerRunning = true;
    _timer.Start(); 
}

private void OnTimerElapsed(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    _isTimerRunning = false;
    _timer.Stop();

    base.OnCollectionChanged(
        new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
}
```

Again you have to do something similar for `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

Note that in both cases we drop some information because `CollectionChanged` won't fire, for example, with `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add` but only with `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`. Anyway if it's just for binding then you're more interested to `INotifyPropertyChanged` notifications and this should not be a problem.